# A problem on interpolation

Tags: real-analysis, interpolation

Given $X(0) \in \Bbb R$ and a continuous and bounded real-valued function $g(.)$ from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, for $\delta > 0$ define the sequence $\{X_n^\delta\}$ by $\{X_0^\delta\} = X(0)$ and

$$ X_{n+1}^\delta =  X_{n}^{\delta} + \delta g(X_{n}^{\delta}), n \geq 0$$

Define the piecewise linear interpolation $X^{\delta}(.)$ by

$$X^{\delta}(t) = \frac{t-n\delta}{\delta} X_{n+1}^\delta + \frac{n\delta +\delta -t}{\delta} X_{n}^\delta \text{ on }[n\delta, n\delta + \delta).$$

Then I need to prove that
$$ X^{\delta}(t) = X(0) + \int_{0}^{t} g(X^{\delta}(s))ds + \rho^{\delta}(t)$$

where the interpolation error goes to zero as $\delta\to 0$.

I am not much aware of such things. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: Show that $X$ grows linearly with a bounded slope, then the values of $X$ over $[0,t]$ lie inside a compact interval where $g$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Essentially, this asks you to show that the Euler forward method of numerical integration of ODE gives a good approximation of a solution if $δ$ is small enough.

Comment: @LutzL: got it. It is just 1st order Taylor's series expansion.

Comment: That would require a differentiable function. $g$ is continuous and bounded, no statement regarding differentiability.